# return sequence type of a soap response

Tags: xml, soap, xquery

In reference to

> [Difference between / and /root-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22169247/difference-between-and-root-node)

i am understanding that root node is the same as document node and that the root element is the same as document element. am i understanding it correctly?

can you please confirm that in my sample soap response

1. **S:Envelope** is the root node AND the document node
2. **S:Envelope** is also the root element AND the document element
3. will **document-node()** be the return sequence type of this soap response that i should use in my *XQuery* declare function signature for the soap request giving this soap response?
4. or should it be something else like **node()*, or item()* or element()***

thanks a lot
apaw

i have this soap response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:searchResponse xmlns:ns2="ws.s.b.d.com">
      <return>
        ... snipped ...
        <businessName>GREEN NATURE WATER REFILLING STATION</businessName>
        <province>PROVINCE AA</province>
        <referenceNumber>12345678</referenceNumber>
        ... snipped ...
        <status>Registered</status>
      </return>
      ... snipped a lot of <return> ... </return> ...
      <return>
        ... snipped ...
        <businessName>129 GREEN AVENUE STORE</businessName>
        <province>PROVINCE BB</province>
        <referenceNumber>12345670</referenceNumber>
        ... snipped ...
        <status>Registered</status>
      </return>
    </ns2:searchResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good question and is often a source of confusion.

In the [XDM (XQuery/XPath Data Model)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-30), a document node is not the same thing as an element node:

- A document node encapsulates a whole XML document and is not visible in the syntax.
- An element node is visible in the syntax as surrounded by angle brackets. S:Envelope is thus an element node.

If the document is parsed with, say, the **doc()** function, or **parse-xml()**, what is returned is a document node (type **document-node()**) and the element **S:Envelope** (type **element()** or **element(S:Envelope)**) will be a child of this document node. I think it would be advisable to stick to this convention for user-defined functions as well.

(Note: other functions may give you a tree without the top-level document node, in which case the tree is called a fragment rather than a document.)

Many different wordings exist for qualifying an element node that is a child of a document node. In the [XML infoset](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-infoset/), **S:Envelop** would be called a *document element* because it is the top-level element information item right under the document information item. But the root itself is the document, not the document element.

Regarding the statement that a *root node* is a document node and a root element the document element, this requires caution. If the tree is a fragment, the *root node* will not be a document node (see [this part](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-30/#terminology) of the XDM specification) but an element node. *root element* is not an official terminology in either data model.

In short, to address the bullet points:

1. S:Envelope is the root node AND the document node: no and no if the tree is a document (e.g., obtained with **doc()**), yes and no if the tree is a fragment.
2. S:Envelope is also the root element AND the document element: no and yes if the tree is a document, yes and no if it is a fragment.
3. will document-node() be the return sequence type of this soap response that i should use in my xquery declare function signature for the soap request giving this soap response: It depends if what this function returns is **S:Envelope** itself, or a document node that wraps it.